# pwa angular 8 doesn't show "add to my home screen popup"

Tags: android, angular, progressive-web-apps

my app is a an angular pwa, but it's not suggesting to install on google chrome, the button is also not showing up and also on f12, application, identification the button to add to home screen is not there.
Anything wrong with my manifest?

```
{
  "name": "aaaa",
  "short_name": "aaa",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "/aaa/",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "prefer_related_applications": true,

  "icons": [

    {
      "src": "assets/icons/android-icon-36x36.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/android-icon-48x48.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },

    {
      "src": "assets/icons/android-icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/android-icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/android-icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/android-icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png",
      "sizes": "57x57",
      "type": "image/png"
    },  
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icons-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }

  ]
}
```

the images are indeed in those locations and I have zero errors when I run lighthouse audits

Comment: You are running on an HTTPS server and you are sure you have TOTALLY cleared out your browser cache and have uninstalled any previous installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the criteria for this to show up is that `prefer_related_applications` cannot be true, which it is in your manifest.

You can check the documentation for it here:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

Comment: even removing it or changing it to false doesn't make my app become instalable , even though I am not failing any criteria

Comment: Did you meet the `Meets a user engagement heuristic` criterium? It's kinda fuzzy but it means you don't get the prompt immediately on page load but you have to interact with the page first. If so, can you check if the `beforeinstallprompt` is fired like they say in the article?

Comment: Are you serving the app via HTTPS and do you have a running Service Worker?